# adding all list value to to dataframe

Tags: list, python-2.7, pandas

I have a list consisting of several string as shown below `list=['abc','cde','fgh']` I want to add all the values to a particular index of dataframe. I am trying it with the code

```
df1.ix[1,3]=[list]
df1.to_csv('test.csv', sep=',')
```

I want in dataframe at poistion 1,3 all values to be inserted as it is `['abc','cde','fgh']`. I don't want to convert it to string or any other format. But it is giving me error. what I am doing wrong here

Comment: What is error? What is `df1.info()` ?

Comment: the error is ----raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray

Comment: Can you add sample of df1? Please check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
df1.ix[1,3] = L
```

Also is not recommended use variable `list`, because code word in python.

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[1,2,3], 'c':[1,2,3], 'd':[1,2,3]})
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3

L = ['abc','cde','fgh'] 
df1.ix[1,3]= L

print (df1)
   a  b  c                d
0  1  1  1                1
1  2  2  2  [abc, cde, fgh]
2  3  3  3                3
```

Comment: still have this error ----  raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value ' ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: It return error with my sample? Or sample works and problem is with real data?

Comment: What is your pandas version `print pd.show_info()` ?

Comment: version is 0.19.0

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use `1:3` not `1,3`

consider the `pd.DataFrame` `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list('xxxxxxx')))
```

---

***use `loc` or `ix`***
`df.loc[1:3, 'A'] = ['abc', 'cde', 'fgh']`
***or***
`df.ix[1:3, 'A'] = ['abc', 'cde', 'fgh']`
***yields***
[image]